# Session var doesn't works after verify page

Tags: php, session, var

I'm having problem with my session var, when I go on my connexion page, I fill username and password. And then it go on my verif page, everything works, my session var works too. But when I go on another page, all my session var are empty.

There is a session_start() in all my page, because it's contained in my header and I include it in all of them.

Here is my var in my login verification page :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Username'] = $identifiant;
$_SESSION['Nom'] = $data['Nom'];
$_SESSION['Prenom'] = $data['Prenom'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $data['ID'];
$_SESSION['Statut'] = $data['Statut'];
```

Comment: [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) -- perhaps you have some sort of output prior to the `session_start();` call.

Comment: post your "another page" code

Comment: I have this error : `Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Projet/index.php on line 38` and there is my line `if($_SESSION['id'] == 0)`

Comment: @Vigikaran it don't works on all my page. So it's not an error on only one

Comment: Write this:- if(isset($_SESSION['Username']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['Username'];
}else{
   echo 'session not set';
}

Comment: You can also check if the session actually is started: `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) { echo "Session has not been started"; }`

Comment: It write me, session not set. And @Qirel you line doesn't works.

Comment: And all my database connexion works, it's not a problem with my db, but only with my session I think

Comment: @FlorianSL: Have you tried my comment?

Comment: @RaviHirani Yes, it print me session not set..

Comment: Now check view page source in browser. Make sure session_start(); line is written there or not.

Comment: Note: I've just updated to php 7.0 some days ago

Comment: I found something, it don't works on Safari, but on Chrome my session works